# New line in JSON

Tags: apex, json

How should I add a new line to JSON? I have tried adding

- "\n"
- "\\n"
- "\\n"
  and nothing works. It simply prints '\n' into the json string.
  This is the sample code: 
   `Account a = new Account();  a.Name = 'Test Account\\\\n Testing';  System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(a.Name));`   
  This is printing 
  [image]

Comment: whats problem in this kind of json - 
`{
 "Text_Message": "Hi There \n How are you?"
}`

Comment: The above one is valid JSON can be parsed through.

Comment: Yup, The JSON is saved on field in salesforce and should display new line visually

Comment: This appears to be an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You want to show the newline, and you're not sure how. You need to include the source code for how you're showing/displaying this value.

Comment: Not sure where you're doing this, or how you're displaying it, but have you tried `\\\\n`? It's bit random but I remember there I was *somewhere* in the platform years ago and needed to do that to get through two levels of escaping - i.e. `\\\\n` would get boiled down to `\\n` and that in turn to the desired `\n`.

Comment: I have updated my question with a sample code, I have tried the latest suggestion by @MattLacey but to no avail.

Comment: check the json data on web page (front end tech). Debug masks lot of things

Comment: it is not displayed on the UI. We are logging the JSON API request into a field and I see the same behaviour.

Comment: Are there any more clues on solving this?